# after_create callback not firing on Model created with nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class User
  has_many :submissions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :submissions, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Submission
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :send_confirmation

  def send_confirmation
    UserMailer.confirm_submission(self)
  end
end
```

In the Controller the Submission model is created by the user model

```
def create
  @user = User.where(:email => user_params[:email]).first_or_create
  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
end
```

The after_create callback is not firing for the Submission model.

How can I get this callback to work?

Comment: Please try `after_save` instead of `after_create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a `after_create` callback on the `Submission` class. I guess you expect than setting submissions attributes in your form to "create" a new submission.

But look at the code in the controller:

```
@user = User.where(:email => user_params[:email]).first_or_create
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

Here is what you are doing:

1. Create a new `User` if not found
2. Update user's instance with `user_params`

Assuming `user_params` contains your submissions attributes, you are not "creating" but "updating" the instance.

You need to define a `after_update` or `after_save` callback:

```
class Submission
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :send_confirmation

  def send_confirmation
    UserMailer.confirm_submission(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `after_save` instead of `after_create`

```
 class Submission    
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :send_confirmation

   def send_confirmation
    UserMailer.confirm_submission(self)
   end  
  end
```

thanks